# Managing views and api from the same controller

Tags: laravel, api

I have an issue with my app, that is "hybrid", what I mean by "hybrid" controllers have to manage both views ans APIs.

So, basically, for each controller, I must check:

```
if $request->wantsJson(){
    ... // Client rendering using Angular, return json
}else{
   // Server rendering Using blade, return view
}
```

I don't like the fact to have a conditional in every controller method.

I also wouldn't like to have a API folder with a copy of all my controller, there would be a lot of duplicated code.

How should I do it?

Comment: make your code more modular this might help you to duplicate code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest to create a separate class to handle output ex: `class ResultOutput` with the method, `output`.

So, in your controller, when you are ready to output your data, just create a new instance of ResultOutput class, and call method `output` with relevant data.

In ResultOutput class, inject Request object so you can determine the method of the output based on above logic.

Ex: In your controller:

```
return (new ResultOutput())->output($data);
```

In ResultOutput class:

```
class ResultOutput()
{
    private $type;

    public __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->output = 'view';     
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            $this->output = 'json';
        }
    }


    public method output($data) {
        if ($this->type =='view') {
            // return the view with data
        } else {
            // return the json output
        }
    }

}
```

In this way, if you need to introduce new output method (ex: xml), you can do it without changing all your controllers.

Comment: another way will be to extend the view class and modify the make method

Comment: do i need to register 2 routes both in the web.php and api.php files?